# How to customize the paginator from PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, pagination

I want to customize *PrimeFace*'s data table pagination.

It is currently showing the page count at the bottom as: `(1 of 5)`. I want to display the # of records in one page out of total number of records, such as: `(1-10 of 50)`.

I have included my code below - but it isn't working. Could anyone please assist?

```
<p:dataTable id="tblStatusSearch" var="item" rowIndexVar="rowStatusSearch"      
    rows="10" paginator="true"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  
    {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "
    value="#{StatusAction.listEBeans}"

<f:facet name="footer"> 
    <h:outputText value="#{rowStatusSearch + 1} - 10 out of #{bondLocationStatusAction.itemCount}"/>
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use a PrimeFaces `currentPageReportTemplate` for the **CurrentPageReport** like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblStatusSearch" var="item" paginator="true" rows="10"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  
{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} "
    value="#{StatusAction.listEBeans}">
```

I confirm that it works in PrimeFaces 3.4.2. It is present in the users guide for PrimeFaces 3.0, so if you are using PrimeFaces 3.x it should work for you.

Comment: It's working but : after filtering I have : "Showing 1-23 out of undefined". How we could manage this feature with filtering ? (Resolve the undefined error ?)

Comment: I don't have your problem when filtering is used. I found a PrimeFaces issue similar to yours: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5621. Your problem is different then the one ask by OP and should be handled in another question. You can search if your problem has an answer on SO. If not, you should ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: Strange, because it's the same code, and it's clearly not a problem of PF version.

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your purpose i think.

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable" var="car" value="#{myBean.cars}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}"
currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}">
<p:column...../>
<p:column...../>
</p:datatable>
```

In place of {CurrentPageReport} you will be able to see what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`"please refer to the attached image"` I think you have forgotten to attach image ;)

If you want to show the page size in your `p:datatable` you should declare two fields in your bean and hold the `pageSize` and `first` arguments values form `load` method inside them then you can show the page size with following `paginatorTemplate`:

`paginatorTemplate=" {CurrentPageReport} #{yourBean.first + yourBean.pageSize}  and rest of you template "`

remember that `EL` works in `paginatorTemplate` property.