# Display p:dataTable Row Numbers

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In mkyong [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-display-datatable-row-numbers-in-jsf/), they show How To Display DataTable Row Numbers In JSF. They use javax.faces.model.DataModel to get row index without using backing bean value. How to achieve this by using primfaces p:dataTable. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136967/how-to-customize-the-paginator-from-primefaces-datatable

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136967/how-to-customize-the-paginator-from-primefaces-datatable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In primefaces p:datatable component, the component has rowIndexVar attribute, which is used to iterate to refer each row index. Thus, you can do like my example below

```
<p:dataTable 
             var="cmr01Forms" 
             value="#{cmr01Bean.cmr01Forms}"
             rowIndexVar="index">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="index" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText 
            value="#{index + 1}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ***
```

- you can use rowindex. rowIndexVar="rowIndex". it starts with 0 so you
  ve to plus 1 every row

---

```
<p:dataTable var="kat" value="#{kategoriBean.kategoriler}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
        <!--        <p:column headerText="Kategori Id"> -->
        <!--            <h:outputText value="#{kat.Id}" /> -->
        <!--        </p:column> -->
        <p:column headerText="NO">
            <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Kategori Adı">
            <h:outputText value="#{kat.kategoriAdi}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{kat.kategoriKisaAciklama}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```