# Update count of rows of datatable after filtering

Tags: jsf, filter, primefaces, datatable

I have a Java webapp with a Primefaces Data Table with filtering enabled. I want to display the row count of the table. I'm using an ajax call to update the row count. The problem ist, that the update call is called before filtering. So every time I filter I see the row count of the previois filtering result.

Primefaces:

```
<p:outputLabel id=count value="#{myClass.displayedCount}" />
<p:dataTable <!-- filter and all the stuff --> ...>
   <p:ajax event="filter" update=":count"></p:ajax>
```

JavaCode:

```
public int getDisplayedCount() {
   displayedCount = filteredData != null ? filteredData.size() : data.size();
   return displayedCount;
}
```

Example:
default count is 10, after the first filtering the count is still 10 but in the table are only 5 entries displayed. After another filtering the count is 5 but there are 7 entries in the table.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't the `{totalRecords}` key in [paginator templates](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/datatable?id=paginator-template) solve your challenge?

Comment: Doesn't {totalRecords} show the value of all entries in the datatable without regarding the filtering? So if there are 10 rows in total and only 1 is visible due to filtering, woudln't it still show 10?

Comment: I tested it, it works, I was wrong with my assumption. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As @Selaron suggested in the comments, I used {totalRecords} in the dataTable

```
<p:dataTable ... paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} " currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}">
```

I added `paginatorTemplate` and `currentPageReportTemplate` to dataTable. But I'm sure exactly sure, what `paginatorTemplate` does. Can anyone explain me that?

But the problem is solved with this.

Thanks to @Selaron.

Comment: Further references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136967/how-to-customize-the-paginator-from-primefaces-datatable